# Is garage door insulation beneficial in South Florida?

Tags: insulation, garage-door

I'm in South Florida and I have a west exposed garage door. The garage door is metal (possibly aluminum). The garage is not air conditioned. There is insulation between the house and the garage. There is no insulation in the garage walls, which are concrete blocks covered with stucco.

Would there be any benefit to adding insulation to my existing garage door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience insulated garage doors are terrible in the summer. While they do a fantastic job keeping the heat in during cold winter months, the lack of ductwork for actively cooling the space makes it into somewhat of a heat-trap with temperatures regularly hitting 120F when its only 90F outside.

This all changes though if you have AC running into the garage, in which case I imagine they'd be great.

Comment: Your answer was very useful.  I was hoping that the insulation would keep the garage temperatures lower in the summer.  But it looks like that is not the case.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping that as well :/ Glad you found it helpful though!

Answer (score 2):

Seems unlikely, especially as the garage walls aren't insulated (although concrete blocks and stucco will add a lot of thermal mass). If you're worried about the garage getting too hot, then ventilation and white paint are probably your best solutions.

Comment: A small clarification, the garage walls are concrete blocks with stucco over it.  Only the garage door is metal.

Comment: You can insulate the garage door, but with an annoying amount of effort. You would install furring strips, then 2" or 3" thick fiberglass insulation, then lay plywood over that. You would essentially be building a thin wall with minor benefits.

Comment: I've come across styrofoam insulating panels at home depot.  http://m.homedepot.com/p/Garage-Door-Insulation-Kit-8-Pieces-Garage-Door-Insulation-Kit-8-pcs/203630159

Comment: They make garage door panels with embedded insulation.